# LimeSurvey + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Eu estou tentando desenvolver um app que gerencia alguns `surveys` oriundos do `limeSurvey` e para esse propósito eu estou usando `Hibernate`. Então, o problema todo é que o `limeSurvey` me dá as respostas de cada `survey` desse jeito:

```
lime_survey_id(Table)
```

Onde cada `id` é relativo a um `survey` específico.

Tudo que eu gostaria era pegar a lista de todas as respostas de todos os `surveys` usando `hibernate`. O problema é: Como eu faço isso? Eu tenho a lista de todos os ids em outra table.

Ps¹: Eu estou usando `Spring` também. Ps²: Eu estou usando `EntityManager` para lidar com as tabelas. Ps³: Eu estou realmente um newbie/inexperiente. Ps4: Na verdade eu pensei em outro jeito de resolver meu problema(Transformar todas as tabelas que o `limeSurvey` me dá em uma única table. Porém, eu penso que isso seria muito mais difícil.

Comment: Olé, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow, passe pelo nosso tour para saber mais sobre a comunidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Poste aqui o código que você já tem, fica mais fácil de entender seu problema e ajudar.

Comment: Mas não tem código para esse problema(Já que não sei resolver esse problema). .-.. Porém, vou tentar explicar um pouco melhor. O limeSurvey  fornece um .sql onde nele se encontra várias informações dos seus surveys(Tais como respostas dos surveys, nomes, etc) e cada dado está representado em uma tabela. As respostas do survey estão como: lime_survey_id(Table). Porém, no hibernate cada tabela representa uma entidade(no caso, uma classe em java), porém, eu quero pegar todas as respostas(lime_survey_42342; lime_survey_432423...) sem precisar fazer x entidades.

Comment: Então você quer usar o Hibernate mas não quer ao mesmo tempo?